# After migrating a question, is my account created forcefully?

Tags: support, questions, user-accounts, migrated-questions

Suppose I have answered to a question or posted a question. That question is moved to some other stack exchange site.

- After my question is migrated, is my account created forcefully?
- Will accounts be created for all users who have answered the question?
- Will my reputation, which I gained before the question was migrated, be lost/transferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, user accounts are not automatically created upon migration, either for the asker or the answerer(s). That feature [has been proposed and declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84657/auto-create-user-account-on-migration-of-questions). However, you can create an account on the new site, link it to your existing account(s), and [everything will work peachy-keen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125594/153008).

And yes, you will lose the reputation you've earned from a question that has been migrated. Reputation is not migrated between sites. At least, that's [how it *used* to work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges); I'm not sure if there were any changes made to the system in the process of eradicating [the migration bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124956/153008).

Comment: But I got my lost reputation after logging in that migrated question's site?

Comment: @Som: Yes, [as Jeff says in the answer I linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6458/153008): *"Question and answer votes are preserved on the destination site and are cast by the Community user. These migrated votes will confer reputation."*